# how to bulk load fix width csv file to a table with the same length for all columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, bulkinsert, fixed

I want to load the data without create the table first, so the table created will be based on the configure file,since the file is with fixed width field,  by default it will use the LENGTH as the max varchar length, such as if LENGTH="18" (the first column), the column will be create as varchar(18). But I need all the columns to be create with the same length, such as varchar(100), how to do that?  (another story: why I need it, because when unpivot a table, it needs all the columns with the same length)

```
<RECORD>
  <FIELD ID="1" xsi:type="CharFixed" LENGTH="18" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
  <FIELD ID="2" xsi:type="CharFixed" LENGTH="8" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
  <FIELD ID="3" xsi:type="CharFixed" LENGTH="18" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
  <FIELD ID="4" xsi:type="CharFixed" LENGTH="3" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
  <FIELD ID="5" xsi:type="CharFixed" LENGTH="3" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
  <FIELD ID="6" xsi:type="CharFixed" LENGTH="3" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
  <FIELD ID="7" xsi:type="CharFixed" LENGTH="18" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
  <FIELD ID="8" xsi:type="CharFixed" LENGTH="2" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
  <FIELD ID="9" xsi:type="CharFixed" LENGTH="5" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
  <FIELD ID="10" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="\r\n" MAX_LENGTH="5" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
 </RECORD>
```

Comment: I am obviously missing something, but why not set all the length= statements to the maximum length from all the columns?

Comment: I use this workaround: first create a table with the same length, and then insert into this table. But if we the file format changed, we need to change the table definition also. If I can use select * into tab from openrowset(..), and sql server can automatically create a table with all the columns of the same length, then I don't need to change the code for every loading file

Answer (score 1):

You could dynamically build a global temp table from the input file.

Initially, the csv file is loaded into a temp table with one column. Then the SQL statements are built to create a global temp table and then bulk copy again to populate it.

**Notice** that the FIELDTERMINATOR = ',' changes in the second bulk copy.

```
declare @ix int; 

-- bulk insert into a table with one row
create table #CSV (Col1 varchar(8000))

BULK INSERT #CSV
FROM 'c:\temp\BulkCopyTest.txt'
WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR = '||', ROWTERMINATOR = '\n', FIRSTROW=1)

-- dynamically create a CREATE TABLE statement
declare @CreateTableSQL varchar(8000);
set @CreateTableSQL = 'create table ##T (';

declare @Row varchar(8000);
select top 1 @Row = col1 from #CSV;

-- split apart the row
set @ix = 1;
while (charindex(',',@Row)>0)
begin
    set @CreateTableSQL = @CreateTableSQL + 'COL'+convert(varchar,@ix)+' varchar(100), ';
    set @Row = substring(@Row,charindex(',',@Row)+1,len(@Row))
    set @ix = @ix + 1
end
set @CreateTableSQL = @CreateTableSQL + 'COL'+convert(varchar,@ix)+' varchar(100))';

-- create the temp table
exec( @CreateTableSQL );

-- populate the temp table
BULK INSERT ##T
FROM 'c:\temp\BulkCopyTest.txt'
WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR = ',', ROWTERMINATOR = '\n', FIRSTROW=1)


select * from ##T;
.
.
.
drop table ##T
drop table #CSV
```